# using external ivy for sbt build

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

At my work place we are starting to use Scala. For dependencies and building we use an ivy.xml file. I am struggling to get the build.sbt to work with the ivy.xml.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#External+Maven+or+Ivy
I checked out this guide, but the example code did not work.
[below is what I have in my build.sbt]

```scala
externalIvyFile(Def.setting(baseDirectory.value / "ivy.xml"))
classpathConfiguration in Compile := Compile
classpathConfiguration in Test := Test
classpathConfiguration in Runtime := Runtime
```

```sh
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: unrecognized module settings: IvyFileConfiguration(false, Some(ScalaModuleInfo(2.12.8, 2.12, Vector(), true, false, true, org.scala-lang, Vector(scala-library, scala-compiler, scala-reflect, scala-actors, scalap))), /work/scalawork/local.study.exchanger/ivy.xml, true)
```

Above is the error code I am getting back.
sbt-1.2.8
scala-2.12.8
ivy-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `externalIvySettings()` at the top of your build.sbt?

```
externalIvySettings()
externalIvyFile(Def.setting(baseDirectory.value / "ivy.xml"))
classpathConfiguration in Compile := Compile
classpathConfiguration in Test := Test
classpathConfiguration in Runtime := Runtime
```

Comment: No, as it is optional, and we don't use external settings files. However I tried adding that line and still got the same error. Good question though.